# Sampling Records from Hadoop Mapper

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have a dataset whose key consists of 3 parts: a, b and c. In my mapper, I would like to emit records with the key as 'a' and the value as 'a,b,c'

How do I emit 10% of the total records for each 'a' that is detected from the mapper in Hadoop? Should one consider saving the total number of records seen for each 'a' from a previous Map-Reduce job in a temp file?

Comment: Does it need to be exactly 10% or close to 10%?

Comment: The former, but I would love to hear the answer for both. I'm guessing with the latter, it will be similar to reservoir sampling?

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking.  Otherwise you'll likely need to count the number of keys in the map stage and then use that to emit only 10% in the reduce.  Just a thought

Answer (score 0):

If you want close to 10%, you can use Random. Here is an example of Mapper:

```
public class Test extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text> {

    private Random r = new Random();

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (r.nextInt(10) == 0) {
            context.write(key, value);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this java code to select 10% randomly:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class RandomSample {

 public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (Math.random()<0.1)
            context.write(value,null);
        else
            context.write(null,null);
    context.write(value,null);
    } 
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = new Job(conf, "randomsample");
    job.setJarByClass(RandomSample.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
 }

}
```

And use this bash script to run it

```
echo "Running Job"
hadoop jar RandomSample.jar RandomSample $1 tmp
echo "copying result to local path (RandomSample)"
hadoop fs -getmerge tmp RandomSample
echo "Clean up"
hadoop fs -rmr tmp
```

For example, if we name the script `random_sample.sh`, to select 10% from folder `/example/`, simply run

```
./random_sample.sh /example/
```